# Include stdlib.h :No such file or directory in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, include

I compiled my c++ program in the directory

```
  D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin
```

But stdlib.h is present in the path.

```
  D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include
```

While compiling my program, it throws the following error in the command prompt.

```
fatal error c1083:cannot open include file:"stdlib.h":No such file or directory 
NMAKE : fatal error U1077 :'.\c1.exe' : return code '0x2
```

How to solve this issue.Please take a look into it.

Thanks.'

Comment: did you try "#include <cstdlib>"? Usually you don't include the c standard lib directly when using c++.

Comment: @PeterT :I tried cstdlib.The same error is throwing.

Comment: I also added the include path in the environmental variable.That also not helps.

Comment: are you compiling with visual studio 2008 and does this happen when you create a new solution and just include this file and call `rand();` in the main?

Comment: I am compiling my c file in the bin folder.I am using visual studio 2008.I am not creating any solution file.I am compiling using command prompt.

Comment: do you at least use the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt? If not then you have to enter the include paths in the `INCLUDE` environment variable or the `/I` command line option, see the "Microsoft Specific" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you compile from the command-line, you should use the `Visual Studio Command Prompt` as it sets common environment variables that are used for compiling.

If for some reason you insist on using `cmd.exe` then you have to either add the include paths to the `INCLUDE` environment variable or you have to give the compiler the command-line parameter `/IC:\Path\to\include`

Details are available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

**edit:** well since this got recently upvoted I might as well add what I forgot last time. If you want to set up the environment variables that the `Visual Studio Command Prompt` uses you can just execute the **`vcvarsall.bat`** which is located in a directory like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC` for details consult the [relevant MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx)

Comment: If you’re using Visual Studio build tool, run `Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` on `cmd` and it’ll set everything up on the console for you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the right platform toolset selected.

Project -> properties -> configuration properties -> Platform toolset

If you move a project from computer to computer via a flash drive or something, it can have an invalid toolset selected.  That can cause intellisense to tell you that.